# How can I prevent Skype from suggesting me to other people?

Tags: skype, windows-live

How can I keep my Skype profile from coming up as suggestions on other people's Skype account, even though I have their phone/email on my phone, or they have my phone/email on theirs?

Comment: Please [edit] and remove the rant from your question.

Comment: Don't use skype.

Comment: I understand you are upset but for us to actually help you, you need to strip out all the emotion and ask the simple question.

Comment: Not sure we can help you here. There is no way for us to know who and how anyone is using your information. You need to do as David Postill and Eric F have suggested. Otherwise, this question will end up closed.

Comment: Good points. Updating now.

Comment: I took my -1 off since you updated as we requested

Answer (score 2):

It is not currently possible to make your profile "private", which would in essence accomplish what you want. Skype allows certain parts of your profile to remain private, like your age or location, but name and email address are public (or, at least searchable).

From the Skype forums:

> Your profile information cannot be completely hidden as it is used in the Skype directory so that people can actually find you.  Similar to a phone directory.  Some options are statically public.  If you do not want that information to be public it would be best to keep it blank.  My profile on all my accounts remain as blank as can be.  If people need to find me in the directory I provide them with my Skype name or e-mail address.  To view your profile information and edit it just press "Ctrl - I" while in Skype.  It is less restrictive than editing your profile on the website.

One alternative would be to use a proxy email address, and disable the app's permissions to your contact address book on your phone. That is not a setting in the app, but rather the phone OS.

It is also certainly possible that Skype uses "spider-web" suggestions. Their servers look for common friendships, and similarly to Facebook, suggests you to people that are more mathematically likely to know you. The only way to stop Microsoft - or any social network for that matter - from doing this (if they are), is to stop using their product, as they don't give you the option to disable it.

Comment: I do like your advice to OP about the proxy email.

Answer (score 1):

Although not really a fantastic answer.. Skype suggests the following:

> Set all profile settings as "blank" or "not specified," particularly the Gender setting. Remember if you input data into those settings which Skype has set by default to appear in public, that information will indeed appear to the public.  Replace a picture of yourself with a bland or neutral avatar. Look uninteresting.

So basically there is not much you can do other than hide your information.